# iframe logging error ' can't read property 'contentWindow' of null

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, iframe

there is an api response in a website which can't be accessed outside this site requests. I want to access it response.

to do that I am trying iframe with code:-

html

```
<iframe id="myFrame" src="https://abrahamjuliot.github.io/creepjs" title="creepJS"></iframe>
```

css

```
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; top: 0;
    height:0; width:0;
    border: none;
}
```

Javascript

```
console.log(fingerprint);
```

it is basically behind a loading screen

:-

full html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="loading.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="loading.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <meta charset="utf-8"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
    <title>Device Verification</title>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe id="myFrame" src="https://abrahamjuliot.github.io/creepjs" title="creepJS"></iframe>
    <div class="contents">
      
      <div class="load-icon center">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>
      <h3>Verifying your Device for Security  Reasons before accessing your account</h3><div class="text-area">
      <p>This process is automatic. Your browser will redirect you to your requested content shortly. 
      </div>
     </p>
     <div class="load-text-area">
    <p>  We request you to allow us upto 5 seconds.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class ="last">
    <p>Verification id is <mark class="purple-dark">41E78vF6
    </mark></p></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Full css

```
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
}


h3 {
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 2%;
  padding-top: 8%; 
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: roboto;
}



.contents {
  margin-top: 30%;
  
}

.text-area {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  font-family: roboto;
  margin-top: 4%;
  
}

.load-text-area{
  margin-left: 3.5%;
  font-family: roboto;
  margin-top: 15%;
}

mark.purple-dark{
  color: purple;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.last{
  margin-left: 3.5%;
  font-family: roboto;
  margin-top: 0.2%;
}
.load-icon {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
}
.load-icon span {
    position: absolute;

    display: inline-block;
    background: #222;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.load-icon span:nth-of-type(1) {
    left: 0;
}
.load-icon span:nth-of-type(2) {
    left: 40%;
}
.load-icon span:nth-of-type(3) {
    right: 0;
}

/* Animation */
.load-icon span {
    animation-name: loading;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.load-icon span:nth-of-type(2) {
    animation-delay: .2s;
}
.load-icon span:nth-of-type(3) {
    animation-delay: .4s;
}

/* Keyframes */
@keyframes loading {
    0% { opacity: 1; }
    50% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}

/* This isn't needed, just styling pen. */
.center {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 37%;
  margin-top: 29%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

iframe {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; top: 0;
    height:0; width:0;
    border: none;
}
```

and full js

```
var fingerprint = document.getElementById('myFrame').contentWindow.document.body  

console.log(fingerprint);
```

I am getting 2 error

which is :-

in the image [Dom exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kTtu.jpg)

and 2nd is

iframe logging error ' can't read property 'contentWindow' of null

my current goal is to get json api response:-

[The api response I want to Capture and put it in a file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiaLF.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: No I am facing 2 problems as I mentioned. First was Dom regarding 2nd was iframe can't read property 'contentWindow' of null and My goal is to fetch the api response from the iframe. check the final hyperlink

Comment: The link answers the second one.

Comment: yes but my rest are still pending but I  thank you for help. it got fixed